# How do I load a dll's config file inside another appdomain

Tags: file, dll, configuration, exe, appdomain

I have an application that needs to load an add-on in the form of a dll. The dll needs to take its configuration information from a configuration (app.config) file. I want to dynamically find out the app.config file's name, and the way to do this, as I understand , is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile

However, since it is being hosted INSIDE a parent application, the configuration file that is got from the above piece of code is (parentapplication).exe.config. I am not able to load another appdomain inside the parent application but I'd like to change the configuration file details of the appdomain. How should I be going about this to get the dll's configuration file?

Comment: I'm having this same problem at the moment, and I don't believe there is a solution. See this thread which is more or less the same issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636275/appdomain-and-config-section-typing

Answer (score 3):

OK, in the end, I managed to hack something together which works for me. Perhaps this will help;

Using the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly, from the DLL which has the config file I want to read, I can use the .CodeBase to find where the DLL was before I launched a new AppDomain for it. The *.dll
.config is in that same folder.

Then have to convert the URI (as .CodeBase looks like "file://path/assembly.dll") to get the LocalPath for the ConfigurationManager (which doesn't like Uri formatted strings).

```
try
{
    string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
    string originalAssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.dll", originalAssemblyPath, assemblyName));
    string dllPath = uri.LocalPath;

    configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(dllPath);
}
catch { }
```

Comment: Found a shorter way to convert [URI to local path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2442170/196451): `var dllpath = (new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;`